# Facing an issue with DocumentHelper method in Kentico 10

Tags: kentico

I am using a csv file and adding all products to the kentico database with the help of DocumentHelper methods.

Below is the code which I used while adding products to Kentico database in Kentico 9.0. This works fine

```
public void InsertAttachment(string url, SKUTreeNode productDoc)
    {
        string file = DownloadImage(url);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
        {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(file), true);
            AttachmentInfo attachment = DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(productDoc, "ProductImage", file, tree);
            attachment.AttachmentImageHeight = getRelativeHeight(bmp);
            attachment.AttachmentImageWidth = 300;
            attachment.AttachmentIsUnsorted = true;
            AttachmentInfoProvider.SetAttachmentInfo(attachment);
            productDoc.Update();
        }
    }
```

Same code I use for Kentico 10 but I get an error in the AddAttachment method.It is not accepting the TreeProvider variable “tree”.
Can you please provide me the solution for this or an alternate way through which I might add an attachment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v10 you do not need to supply tree parameter to the method, you can use:

```
attachment = DocumentHelper.AddAttachment(page, "MenuItemTeaserImage", file);
page.Update();
```

Comment: In this link you will find exactly what you are suggesting https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-10/23737.I have one more question that if I replace return type AttachmentInfo with DocumentAttachment (as stated in the link),then what should I do to replace AttachmentInfoProvider.SetAttachmentInfo(attachment) part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the changes made to API in Kentico 10

https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-10/23737